# Multiple connected objects in QT

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I have several Qt objects that notify each other of any changes.

Connecting them with each other without any safeguard would create an infinite loop of signals: object A changes and signals objects B and C; each of B and C sends signals back to A and to C and B respectively; etc. Temporarily disconnecting the other objects when receiving a signal and reconnecting after updating the object kind of barely work, with emphasis on "kind of barely", which includes occasional crashes due to multiple signals coming out of order.

What would you recommend for a safe and robust method of syncing multiple Qt objects?

Comment: The 'usual' method in Qt is a 'model-view' pattern - where the model  holds the shared data and notifies views of changes in response to modifications.

Comment: There are several interfaces to the "model" in my case: GUI, a Tcl interpreter variable, a file that can be loaded from C++ code, etc. Each of them can change the model. For example, a text widget can be both the source of the model change and simultaneously displays the model parameter; a Tcl variable can be set by the user (and should update the model at that time) and may be used by a flow that relies on this variable be updated by the model.

Comment: That's sounds pretty normal to me, Michael. The MVC pattern is an attempt to structure that sort of stuff. The model can have as many 'views' as you like, and they don't all have to care about all aspects of the model...and a model can have as many modifier functions as you like. The main point is that changes are made to the model, and notifications come from the model - so the circularity problem you outline should be circumvented. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Thanks, sje, will check out the pattern you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `QObject::blockSignals` as described [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#blockSignals). But you must remember that if you use `QObject::blockSignals` will bloack all signals until you call `QObject::blockSignals` with `false` parameter.

Comment: Well, I tried something similar: disconnect at the top of signal handling procedure and connect at the bottom. In the question I mentioned that this "kind of barely work". One of the symptoms: you click a button slowly 5 times and everything works; you click it 5 times quickly, causing signals coming out of order, and the system crashes. I'm not sure whether blocking would cause the same disaster as disconnect-update-connect did; will try the pattern suggested by sje 1st.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the values do actually change, both at the receiver side as at the sender side, like this:

```
class A {
    slot:
        setValue(int a) {
            if (a != m_a) {
                m_a = a;
                emit changed();
            }
        }
    private:
        int m_a;
}
```

At least, this should avoid the endless circle.
Of course, an MVC pattern is much better way to handle these kind of updates.